# Hibernate foreign key of type String issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i am trying to connect two tables in a one to one mapping by declaring a first table column (of type String) as foreign key to the second table.

So here are my main two hibernate entities:

Primary entity StudyDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="StudyDetails")
public class StudyDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name="Id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="InternalID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String internalId;

@Column(name="StudyInstanceUID", unique = true)
private String studyInstanceUID;

@Column(name="LastUploadedDate")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime lastUploadedDate; 

@Column(name="IsProcessed")
private boolean isProcessed;

@Column(name="IsUploaded")
private boolean isUploaded;
```

and the second one DicomSeriesMeta:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DicomSeriesMeta")
public class DicomSeriesMeta {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name="Id")
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="InternalID", referencedColumnName="InternalID")
private StudyDetails studyDetails;

public StudyDetails getStudyDetails() {
    return studyDetails;
}

public void setStudyDetails (StudyDetails studyDetails) {
    this.studyDetails = studyDetails;
}

@Column(name="PatientID")
private String patientID;

@Column(name="IssuerOfPatientID")
private String issuerOfPatientID;

@Column(name="PatientSex")
private String patientSex;

@Column(name="PatientName")
private String patientName;

@Column(name="PatientBirthDate")
private String patientBirthDate;
...
}
```

I would like to have StudyDetails.InternalID as foreign key to table DicomSeriesMeta ... It is a unique id of type String generated with a particular algorithm.

I am trying to save a DicomSeriesMeta object in database like:

```
....
DicomSeriesMeta dicomSeriesMeta = new DicomSeriesMeta();
dicomSeriesMeta.setPatientID(patientID);
dicomSeriesMeta.setIssuerOfPatientID(issuerOfPatientID);
dicomSeriesMeta.setPatientSex(patientSex);
dicomSeriesMeta.setPatientName(patientName);
dicomSeriesMeta.setPatientBirthDate(patientBirthDate);
dicomSeriesMeta.setOtherPatientIDs(otherPatientIDs);
....
dicomSeriesMeta.setStudyDetails(getStudyDetailsbyStudyId(studyInstanceUID));
Session s=HibernateUtil.openSession();
s.beginTransaction();
s.save(dicomSeriesMeta);
s.getTransaction().commit();
s.close();
....
```

However i am getting:

```
 Hibernate: insert into DicomSeriesMeta (AccessionNumber, InstitutionAddress, InstitutionName,    IssuerOfPatientID, MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID, OperatorsName, OtherPatientIDs, OtherPatientIDsSequence, PatientAge, PatientBirthDate, PatientID, PatientName, PatientSex, PhysiciansOfRecord, ReferringPhysicianName, RequestingPhysician, SOPInstanceUID, SeriesInstanceUID, StudyDate, InternalID, StudyID, StudyInstanceUID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
  Νοε 24, 2014 4:03:16 ΜΜ com.npap.dicomrouter2.FXMLDocumentController startDcmrcvService
  SEVERE: null
  org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
at    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
at com.npap.utils.ProcessDicomFiles.storeAnonymizationData(ProcessDicomFiles.java:323)
at com.npap.utils.ProcessDicomFiles.anonymizeDicomObj(ProcessDicomFiles.java:233)
at com.npap.utils.AnomynizerFileVisitor.visitFile(AnomynizerFileVisitor.java:24)
at com.npap.utils.AnomynizerFileVisitor.visitFile(AnomynizerFileVisitor.java:15)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
at com.npap.utils.ProcessDicomFiles.anonymizeStudyFolders(ProcessDicomFiles.java:55)
at com.npap.dicomrouter2.FXMLDocumentController.startDcmrcvService(FXMLDocumentController.java:219)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'Id' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
... 90 more
```

Comment: Maybe you should set an id in your insert-query.

Comment: Which column should it be a foreign key of? I'm guessing it's InternalId. But you didn't tell it to Hibernate. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29. Also, you should post the complete stack trace and the code causing the exception to be thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet i am trying to set InternalId as FK, yes. I have declared this on DicomSeriesMeta table (@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)@JoinColumn(name="InternalID")private StudyDetails studyDetails;) ... Do i need to declared it on StudyDetails also?

Comment: My question is "as a FK to *which column* of StudyDetails?". Surely you don't want the varchar DicomSeriesMeta.InternalId column to be a foreign key to the int StudyDetails.Id. That's what your current mapping does, since it doesn't specify any target column name.

Comment: @JBNizet i want also to create a field "InternalID" in DicomSeriesMeta table with the same name as FK from table StudyDetails (StudyDetails.InternalID -FK-> DicomSeriesMeta.InternalID)

Comment: OK. So you should use `referencedColumnName` in your JoinColumn annotation. By default, the referenced column is the primary key (i.e. DicomSeriesMeta.Id). Read the javadoc I linked to.

Comment: @JBNizet used it (referencedColumnName) but same error persists. Do i have to declare mapping table somewhere also? thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I think you auto generate table by Hibernate entities. In this case you need to specify generate strategy. Select what you need:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html